# How to make a get route like "router.get('/region/:id')" but with a limited range for the id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry for the bad title, I didn't really know how to phrase it.

So I have a DB with some regions. Each of them has an unique code. I want all of them to be available in this route, but obviously the ID can be, let's say, from 10-19. If the ID is something else, then 404 should be rendered.

I have an idea on how to do this and it's a middleware. This is how I'd do it:

```js
middleware.doesRegionExist = function(req, res, next)
{
    var regions = [10, 11, 12];
    if(regions.includes(req.params.id))
    {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/404");
}
```

```js
router.get('/regiune/:id', middleware.doesRegionExist, function(req, res, next)
{
    res.send(req.params.id);
});
```

So my questions are: is this the best way to achieve this? I feel like it's not because I have to hardcode an array with the regions available in the middleware.
And why does my idea not work? (I get 404 everytime)

////edit: I had to change the if statement with this: `if(regions.includes(Number(req.params.id)))`. Now it works. Is it the best way to do this though?

////edit2: I have this middleware for checking if the user has access to this variable:

```js
middleware.access = function(req, res, next)
{
    if(!req.isAuthenticated())
    {
        User.findOne({'username': req.body.username, "privileges.region": {$in: [1, req.body.regiune]}}, function(err, usr)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("middleWare.access - " + err);
            return res.redirect("404");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(usr);
            if(usr === null)
            {
                return res.redirect("404");
            }
            else
            {
                return next();
            }
        }
    })
    }
}
```

so I can't use another middleware because I have to use this (and as far as I know you can't use more than 1 middleware in a route). Should I just copy middleware.doesRegionExist into the route?

Comment: The id is supposed to be the mongoId or just a random number sequence?

Comment: I'm doing it step by step so I can learn this. Right now is just a random number sequence for educational purpose haha. In the future it will have to be a mongoId.

Comment: If in future you are planning a mongoId instead, because they are unique and not guaranteed in series, then probably you are doing right by checking if it exists in the allowed array. Cheers :)

Comment: `and as far as I know you can't use more than 1 middleware in a route` You can use as much as you want, of course they should have a purpose and must call to next()

Comment: How can I use more than one middleware in the same route, then? ///nevermind. I found it.

Comment: For express, if you want to use global middlewares, ie for all routes, use, app.use() or router.use() with the middlewares inside that.

Comment: For the specific routes, router.get('/', middlewareA, middlewareB, middlewareC, ... middlewareX, middlewareY, middlewareZ);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things here:

1. restricting route shape to prevent requests like: `GET /region/<very-long-alphanumeric-string>`
2. checking region existence in database and returning 404 if it not exists

**Routing**

Let's start from routing. Express' routes are support regex, so you can configure them very widely. For ex. if you expect to have id in 00-99 range only you can do the following:

```
router.get('/region/:id([0-9]{2})', function(req, res, next){
  const numericId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  // ... your code
  next();
});
```

You can find more details on this topic here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html, https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

**Database handling**

Since your data are not constant over time and stored in database (am I right?), the only robust way to check if data really exists in the moment of making request is to perform database query.

**All in one**

If Region model is mongoose-based, your express handler should be something like this:

```
router.get('/region/:id([0-9]{2})', access, function(req, res, next){
  const numericId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  Region.findOne({regionId: numericId}, function (err, region){
    if(err){
      return res.redirect("404");
    } else {
      if(usr === null){
        return res.redirect("404");
      } else {
        return next();
      }
    }      
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot although I didn't want the query so I could do it myself haha. The part with the regex was the most useful for me, because I didn't know express suports that.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on the need you want to solve, for example:

If the id you are going to analyze is a series of continuous numbers you can verify if the id is in the correct range.

```
const id = Number(req.params.id);
if (id >= 10 && id <= 12) {
    return next();
}
res.redirect("/404");
```

In other cases you can have valid ids in an array or in some other data source.

---

You can have multiple middleware nesting one after another.

```
router.get('/', middleware1, middleware2, middleware3, function (req, res) {
    var model = new IndexModel();
    res.send('<code><pre>' + JSON.stringify(model, null, 2) + '</pre></code>');
});
```

I leave the documentation of [Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) in Express, so you can review the section of ***Route handlers***.